# vb.net DateTime.Parse works but DateTime.ParseExact doesn't

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a date stored as a string. I can use DateTime.Parse to convert it to a date time but DateTime.ParseExact doesn't work.

`Date.Parse("10/05/2023 14:45").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")` works fine and returns the date and can then be outputted using `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")`

`Date.ParseExact("10/05/2023 14:45","dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")` however doesn't work and gives the following error `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

My preference is to use the ParseExact method so I'm keen to get this working but I'm unsure on why it won't work.

Comment: You have 2 digits, 24 hours format: `HH:mm`

Comment: If the current culture matches the Invariant Culture, you get two different dates with `Parse()` and `ParseExact()` here

Comment: @Jimi that worked, do you want to add it as an answer and I'll mark that as the answer, thank you.